# casting in c can cause any compile error?

Tags: c

I know that in java I can't return double from a function that supose to return an int value without casting, but now when I learn c I see that I can compile something like (only warnings, no error):

```
int calc(double d, char c) {
   return d * c / 3;
}
```

so my question is, c compiler will always do for me auto casting when needed?
or this is specific working one because of char or something?

Comment: Yes, such implicit casting is guaranteed by the language, but you'd do well to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: I get no warnings with your code using clang or gcc with -Wall -Wextra, what compiler are you using

Comment: Careful with warnings, they are there for a reason. Whenever your compiler warns you about something, you should take it very seriously and try to eliminate the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your code compiles because there are implicit conversions between all the numeric types. `char` is an integer type.

Answer (score 4):

C has a concept of implicit conversions, i.e. rules that define under which conditions and how values are converted to different types implicitly, without the need to explicitly cast them (see, for example, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)). So C is not "auto-casting" everything, but only under certain conditions.

Your return type is `int`, whereas the result of expression `d * c / 3` is `double`. So the following (implicit) conversion applies:

> **Real floating-integer conversions**
>
> A finite value of any real floating
>   type can be implicitly converted to any integer type. Except where
>   covered by boolean conversion above, the rules are: The fractional
>   part is discarded (truncated towards zero). If the resulting value can
>   be represented by the target type, that value is used otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined

Comment: A reference in your answer to the actual standards document would probably be very useful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that you may not get any warning. The compiler is performing an implicit conversion, and the only way to force it is adding the flag `-Wconversion` (I am talking about gcc, something like: `warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]`). Anyway, the compiler supposes that you know about it, I mean, the decimal value dissapears in case of an integer conversion.

(See YePhIcK's comment about MSVC)

Comment: There's a loss of precision here, so a warning is quite warranted, IMO

Comment: @YePhIcK Actually I have tested it (right now) and the warning is not present (even adding `-pedantic`)

Comment: Not all the compilers are created equal. Try MSVC 2017 ;-) `warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data`

Comment: Of course, that is the reason why I said gcc... I cannot try it under MSVC. Anyway, good point. (I have edited my answer)

Comment: Put it another way - just a few weeks ago our hardware engineer finally found a problem where an image had a "red shift" in the color (coming from the camera) and the problem boiled down to that exact problem: loss of precision. As was commented before: "you'd do well to treat warnings as errors"